# Ao tentar linkar uma NAV, o estilo CSS fica bagunçado

Tags: html, css, div, link

Bom dia pessoal, estou começando aprender front-end e me deparei com um problema que gostaria de entender o porque acontece.

Tenho esse trecho no meu código:

```
       <div class="box-item">
            <div class="box-img">
                <img src="img/base-conhe-icon.png" alt="Icone de base de conhecimento"/>
            </div>
            <div class="box-desc">
                <h1>Documentação</h1>
                <p>.........</p>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Essa div é renderizada dessa forma:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Eu quero linkar toda a DIV pai, porém quando eu uso a tag  envolta da DIV, o resultado é este:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Com certeza no meu HTML e no CSS tem códigos redundantes e talvez técnicas que podem ser consideradas gambiarras, como disse, estou aprendendo. Meu questionamento maior é que sem a tag , fica perfeito, inclusive responsivo. Já com ela, a div é desconfigurada.

HTML: https://pastebin.com/8QeAQHVZ
CSS: https://pastebin.com/tWDEME6d

Pessoal, não reparem se tiver bagunça ou gambiarras, rsrs. Inclusive, peço que chamem minha atenção em pontos que podem ser melhorados. Obrigado!

Comment: É preciso conhecer as CSS para responder. Poste os códigos.

Comment: Pessoal, eu editei a pergunta, no final dela tem os códigos no Pastebin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basicamente basta vc colocar seu `<a>` assim: `<a href="#" class="box-item">` e remover a `<div class="box-item">` de dentro desse `<a>`. Assim vc vai aplicar os estilos direto no `<a>` que agora é filho direto de `<div class="conteudo-principal">` e não vai mais precisar da `div` de dentro

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Massa Hugo, muito obrigado! O conteúdo ta muito bagunçado Hugo? Será que tem alguma dica de melhoria ou algo assim? rsrs

A organização do HTML, CSS, etc.

Comment: @RicardoCássio uma coisa que percebi sem analisar é que é muita linha de CSS teoricamente para pouca coisa. Provavelmente como vc falou tem muita coisa redundante ai... vou olha e te dou umas dicas se estiver ao meu alcance

Comment: Opa, perfeito. Obrigado!

Comment: @RicardoCássio cara na verdade da parte do HTML está tudo bem organizadinho, está ótimo. Com relação ao CSS dei um vacilo aqui eu tinha dado ctrl+v 2x, ai parecia MUITO mais código rss. Tirando isso, vi que vc comentou e separou por partes o CSS isso é bom. A dica que te dou é usar menos *breacking points*, vc não precisa de tantos... E outra coisa é que vc não precisa repetir as coisas a cara *breacking points*. Uma vez que vc declarou algo em um *breacking points* ela já fica valendo dali para baixo, a não sei que vc quera mudar algo novamente, ai vc repete a classe e muda o que for...

Comment: Tipo isso não faz sentido `@media screen and (max-width: 768px){
    .nav-cab{
        display: none;
    } }` e `@media screen and (max-width: 480px){
    .nav-cab{
        display: none;
    } }` uma vez que vc declarou na 768px não precisa declarar na 480px entende. A forma de nomenclatura das classes tb está legal! Vc está no caminho certo, nunca pare de estudar1

Comment: Muito obrigado pela ajuda, pelas dicas e pelo incentivo Hugo. Sucesso!